# Plotting multilevel model coefficients in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, coefplot, multilevel-analysis

I am fitting a 2-level model in R using lme4 for a dataset with multiple election surveys. Im using household income by quintile (ordinal, 5 categories) to predict an outcome variable on the individual level, with individuals nested in survey years.

```
lmer1 <- lmer(y ~ household_income + (household_income|year), data=df)
```

I want a plot with household income on the x axis (the 5 quintiles), with a different line for each country fitted in the plot.

I am not very well versed in ggplot2, any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Where is country in your model?  Are trying to plot the data, or plot the predictions from the model?  Please give a reproducible example showing what you have and what you are trying to achieve.